# Remote gems not listed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am using linux machine. I installed RVM, ruby successfully in my machine. When I give **remote list -r** it shows following error message.

> /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem:4: warning:
>   Insecure world writable dir /home/bathakarai in PATH, mode 040777
>
> *** REMOTE GEMS ***
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>       Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

But it list local gem successfully.

> [bathakarai@Project1-CO ~]$ gem list -l
>   /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem:4: warning:
>   Insecure world writable dir /home/bathakarai in PATH, mode 040777
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> minitest (1.6.0) rake (0.8.7) rdoc (2.5.8)

Please help me out, how to solve this problem

Comment: use "gem list --remote"

Comment: or "gem list --remote | grep 'rails'"

Comment: It also produce the same error message

Comment: use "sudo gem list --remote"

Comment: try sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

**"export $HTTP_PROXY=IPAddress which is given in browser:portnumber"** . For any reference http://khylo.blogspot.in/2007/12/ruby-on-rails-headaches.html